# pytest - Override a test funciton defaullt value

Tags: pytest

i have a pytest testconf and a test function
i want that when running:

```
pytest -q -option="choose_a"
```

it would pass A
and when running

```
pytest
```

it would pass B
the problem is that it does not see 'my_param' in fixtures since it has a default parameter. what can I do to make this working and elegant?

my current temp solution (which I don't like) is removing the default value and assign it with an "if" statement in conftest.pytest_generate_tests....pls give me a better one :)

```
conftest.py:

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--myoption", action="append", default=[], help="list of choices")


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'my_param' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        if 'choose_a' in metafunc.config.option.myoption:
            metafunc.parametrize("my_param", ["A"])
```

mytest.py:

```
def test_my(my_param='B'):
    do_stuff(my_param)
```

Comment: it seems you need a flag. Why are you using `action="append"`. Can you share your real scenario ?

Comment: I actually used the examples i found here:
http://pytest.org/latest/example/parametrize.html#generating-parameters-combinations-depending-on-command-line

the scenario I'm handling is using code that others also use, i don't want to mess with their code too much when I'm testing, and the original code uses a default parameter that I do not want to remove...